# How to turn off simplified configuration of WCF services - .Net 4.0

Tags: wcf

How can I disable the [simplified configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee530014%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) of WCF services with .Net 4.x?

I really wand to disable it, and not just override some bindings or endpoints!

Comment: How do you mean disable? What should happen?

Comment: "In .NET Framework 4, the <service> element is optional. When a service does not define any endpoints, an endpoint for each base address and contract implemented are added to the service" - that wand I disable!

Comment: I can read that. What do you want to happen when the services element is missing?

Comment: The service will not be available - just like befor that, in .Net 3.5